# I can connect to mysql using CLI, but by any external client does not

Tags: mysql, database-connection, ubuntu-16.04

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.

I [installed mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) and I had no problem logging in to it from the command line and from other clients.

Then I completely deleted mysql from the system, using [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/939548/588848) answer.

Later when I needed mysql again I installed it, identically like first time.

And now I can connect to mysql using CLI:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

but by any other client does not...

DBeaver (and other clients) return an error:

> Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost'

My configuration is default:

```
Server Host: localhost
Port: 3306
User name: root
Passwrd: correct_password
```

What could be the reason that this does not work?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By "external" you mean connecting to MySQL from another PC or over the Internet?

When installing MySQL did you enable "external root access"?

Else it is always a good practice to create another user for external connections, as root is "almighty" and should not be used by just anyone.

Comment: No, I was thinking of another, not external. Sorry.
I updated the question.